# Issue while sending request via jQuery AJAX for file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, postman

I have to upload a .pdf file along with some other details as **multipart/form-data** POST request to a URL. I was given a **Postman request** for the same to try.

I have a `curl command` as shown below which I've **exported from Postman**:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://dev.example.com/api/candidates/socially360/ \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: ee4683a0-97d2-4ac9-b2e0-1a2cef24ce7d' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'resume=@C:\Users\Thanthu Nair\Desktop\dp-converted.pdf' \
  -F 'name=Thanthu' \
  -F email=testmail@example.com \
  -F 'phone=+911234567890' \
  -F job=12345 \
  -F 'key=SECRECT_KEY'
```

I want to make this same request with **jQuery AJAX** (or JavaScript XMLHttpRequest will also do). So I **exported the jQuery AJAX code** for the same request **from Postman**. Below is the code:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("resume", "C:\\Users\\Thanthu Nair\\Desktop\\dp-converted.pdf");
form.append("name", "Thanthu");
form.append("email", "testmail@example.com");
form.append("phone", "+911234567890");
form.append("job", "12345");
form.append("key", "SECRECT_KEY");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://dev.example.com/api/candidates/socially360/",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "087fc592-86c7-40d0-a216-dd928fdf5a46"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

But I am getting an a different response in case of the JQuery code (Also tired with JavaScript **XMLHttpRequest** and was getting same response as in case of JQuery). I can't figure out what is the issue.

Also when I copy curl command of the jQuery AJAX request from **Chromes developer console** I am getting the curl as shown below which is **not an issue** but may be it will help to answer.

```
curl "https://dev.example.com/api/candidates/socially360/" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://localhost:8888/view/491/1558604095009_491_53" -H "Origin: http://localhost:8888" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --data-binary ^"------WebKitFormBoundaryUl5oDAlmMjSBqOMq^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"resume^\^"^

^

C:^\^\Users^\^\Thanthu Nair^\^\Desktop^\^\dp-converted.pdf^

------WebKitFormBoundaryUl5oDAlmMjSBqOMq^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"name^\^"^

^

Thanthu^

------WebKitFormBoundaryUl5oDAlmMjSBqOMq^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"email^\^"^

^

testmail@example.com^

------WebKitFormBoundaryUl5oDAlmMjSBqOMq^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"phone^\^"^

^

+911234567890^

------WebKitFormBoundaryUl5oDAlmMjSBqOMq^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"job^\^"^

^

12345^

------WebKitFormBoundaryUl5oDAlmMjSBqOMq^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"key^\^"^

^

SECRECT_KEY^

------WebKitFormBoundaryUl5oDAlmMjSBqOMq--^

^" --compressed
```

**EDIT:**
Below is this code I wrote before trying with code from Postman, which also returned different response.

```
$.ajax({
        url: external.externalUrl,
        data: extData,
        cache: false,
        crossDomain : true,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (res) {
            defer.resolve(JSON.parse(res));
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            defer.reject(new Error(errorThrown));
        }
});
```

**EDIT:**

I am also able to upload with Java code that was exported from Postman, below is the code, so the issue is while uploading from front-end I guess:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"resume\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\Thanthu Nair\\Desktop\\dp-converted.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\nThanthu\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\ntest@example.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"phone\"\r\n\r\n+911234512345\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"job\"\r\n\r\n12345\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"\r\n\r\nSECRET_KEY\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://dev.example.com/api/candidates/socially360/")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("Postman-Token", "523d66c8-b4b9-4d97-a022-94b9adbfc73f")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: removing the `headers` and `mimeType` should solve the problem

Comment: I did try without mimeType and headers. Before I tried code from Postman, I tried with my own code, I'll update that in the question as well and also will try the code in question now after removing mimeType and headers

Comment: what response do you get?

Comment: For the code I exported from Postman after removing `headers` and `mimType` I am getting error message "No error message or detail available." and for the code I wrote I am getting error message "Key not found right." They seem to be custom message from backend, not very helpful

Comment: which version of jquery do you use? if it's > 1.9 then change `type` to `method` and see if the response changes

Comment: also debug your code on the server side and make sure everything works fine and you are returning an object in JSON format to the client and not a string or number

Comment: its greater than 1.9, I'll try that, I cannot debug server, cos the API belongs to a client and we don't have access to the code

Comment: @ElyasEsna changed `type` to `method` still same response

Comment: I think there is some problem with server side and not your code! maybe you are passing wrong key in `key=SECRECT_KEY`

Comment: May be server side, I've sent a mail to check that. `key` is correct, cos its working from Postman. Thanks for your help

Comment: maybe you are not allowed to send a request from clinet side (js). because when you send a request from postman it acts like server to server. I guess you are getting cross origin

Comment: No CORS issue was there earlier before this issue, but that was fixed and my domain is now allowed

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been from server side, cause data was not available for the value of job I was passing in request, when I used code that I wrote which was not exported from Postman since I was passing value that I received from my DB which does not exist in theirs. Below is that code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: external.externalUrl,
        data: extData,
        cache: false,
        crossDomain : true,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (res) {
            defer.resolve(JSON.parse(res));
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            defer.reject(new Error(errorThrown));
        }
});
```

However that does not explain why copy pasting the exact code from Postman did not work since it had the hard coded value for job that worked from Postman.

However since I the issue is solved I am posting this answer.